# The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am getting error

> The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota.

from WCF when running a stored procedure in SQL Server. It is working fine, but in live project it throws an error.

Any solutions? I have done following settings in my application where this WCF consumes.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
      closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:61803/ApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
    contract="Dashboard2WCFData.IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In `web.config` of WCF I have following settings.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect WCF with consumer application by attaching process then you can get exact error cause from WCF exception as per i did in my case here [Getting Error : The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736261/getting-error-the-size-necessary-to-buffer-the-xml-content-exceeded-the-buffer)