# Getting Error : The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota

Tags: asp.net, wcf, console-application

I have developed one console application and from there i have called WCF function after adding as web reference. my console application's web.config as per below..

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
      closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://apicaWCF.cloudapp.net/ApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
    contract="Dashboard2WCFData.IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF" />
</client>
```

I am getting error : The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota. I have also tried it and increased maxbuffersize and etc. still could not resolved this. hope anyone can here help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks.
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got solution , the problem was with stored procedure parameter data type and got this solution using attaching process mechanism in visual studio, so i have debug the wcf function from console application and got exact error in WCF catch block.

Comment: So was the error on the client?  What stored procedure data type?